# Deployment with Ansible in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook to deploy a java application (jar) on AWS EC2. I would like to use it inside a Jenkins pipeline as 'Deploy' step. To deploy on EC2, I need the downloaded private ssh key when the instance was created.

I have 2 choices :

1. Install ansible on the machine hosting Jenkins, insert the private SSH key in Jenkins, and use ansible-playbook plugin to deploy my app
2. Take a base docker image with ansible installed, extend it by inserting my private SSH key, and use this docker image to deploy my app

From a security point of view, what is best ?

Comment: 3. use a secrets management tool 4. use this: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

For option 1, it's recommended to create a new user account, e.g. jenkins in the EC2 instance without sudo privilege, or at least passcode protected sudo 
And it's a good scenario that using Ansible to manage those users accounts, it limits usage of the super key created by AWS

While for option 2, Docker is a good scenario of immutable deployment, which means the configuration should be determined even before the image is ready, so that Ansible is not quite useful in this scenario. 
Different conf means different images to be created 
Maybe you still use Ansible to manage those DockerFiles rather than initiate Ansible and interact with the application itself

The 2 options look quite different from each other in terms of how you design your system more than security concern

Do let me know you need more clarification